# A kind of a " Three Space Property" for commutative strongly graded rings

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, graded-rings

Let $G$ be an abelian group ; let $R=\oplus _{g \in G} R_g$ be a commutative unital $G$-graded ring . For a subgroup $H$ of $G$ we denote by $R_H$ the $H$ graded ring as $R_H = \oplus _{h \in H} R_h$ , where $R_h$ is the $h$-th homogeneous part of the $G$-graded ring $R$  and by $R_{G/H}$ we denote the $G/H$-graded ring $R_{G/H}=\oplus_{g+H \in G/H} (\oplus_{h \in H} R_{g+h})$ . Now a $G$(abelian) -graded ring $R$ is called strongly graded if $R_gR_{g'}=R_{g+g'} , \forall g, g' \in G$ . My question is the following : Let $G$ be an abelian group , and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ . Let $R$ be a commutative unital $G$-graded ring such that $R_H$ and $R_{G/H}$ are strongly graded . Then is $R$ strongly graded ?

If it is not true in general , then is there any extra condition on $G$ or on the subgroup $H$ or on the ring $R$ which forces the assertion to be true ? Has there been any work done on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R_H$ and $R_{G/H}$ are strongly graded.  Let $a,b\in G$, $a+b=c$, and $x\in R_c$.  Since $R_{G/H}$ is strongly graded, there exist $h_i,h_i'\in H$ $y_i\in R_{a+h_i}$ and $z_i\in R_{b+h_i'}$ such that $x=\sum_i y_iz_i$.  Note that then we may discard those $y_i$ and $z_i$ such that $h_i'\neq -h_i$, since then $y_iz_i$ is homogeneous of degree different from $c$ and so all such terms must cancel for the sum to be equal to $x$.  So we may assume $y_i\in R_{a+h_i}$ and $z_i\in R_{b-h_i}$ for each $i$.

Now since $R_H$ is strongly graded, for each $i$, there exist $u_{ij}\in R_{h_i}$ and $v_{ij}\in R_{-h_i}$ such that $\sum_j u_{ij}v_{ij}=1$.  We then have $$x=\sum_i y_iz_i\sum_ju_{ij}v_{ij}=\sum_{i,j}(y_iv_{ij})(z_iu_{ij}).$$  Since $y_iv_{ij}\in R_a$ and $z_iu_{ij}\in R_b$, this shows $x\in R_aR_b$, so $R$ is strongly graded.

Comment: how do you get $x=\sum y_iz_i$ ?

Comment: Since $R_{G/H}$ is strongly graded so $x\in R_{c+H}=R_{a+H}R_{b+H}=(\oplus_{h\in H} R_{a+h})(\oplus _{h\in H} R_{b+h})$ , so shouldn't we have something like $x=(\sum y_h)(\sum z_h) $ ?

Comment: Sure, but you can just expand out that product to get a sum of terms of the form $y_iz_i$.

Comment: ah sure , sorry my bad . Let me read the rest :)

Comment: how can you drop the other terms ? Can it not happen that sum of finitely many homogeneous elements belonging to different degrees actually end up being in a homogeneous part ?

Comment: Yes, but that means that all of the homogeneous parts except those in one degree sum to $0$, so if you remove all those parts it has the same sum.  Just group the terms into those with the same degree, and the sum of each group must be $0$ except for one of them.

Comment: ah okay , got that . And um why do you write $1$ as a sum ? Does $R_gR_{g'}$ means all possible finite sum of products ?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition

Comment: Thanks a lot . I totally understand your proof. D you know what happens if I don't assume $R$ to be commutative ? Does a similar proof work , or is there any counterexample ?

Comment: The proof should work with a slight modification in the noncommutative case.  You just want to arrange that instead $\sum_j v_{ij}u_{ij}=1$, and then write $y_iz_i=y_i\left(\sum_j v_{ij}u_{ij}\right)z_i=\sum_j (y_iv_{ij})(u_{ij}z_i)$ in the last step.